# get file path with python code while .absolute() not fit my answer

Tags: python, linux

I'm using Linux system, extract USB file path using python code.

extract USB path only

**from**

> sdb1   8:17   1   3.8G  0 part /media/joy/DATA
> sdg1   8:97   1  29.4G  0 part /media/joy/DATA2
> sdh1   8:113  1   1.9G  0 part /media/joy/DATA1

**to my expect output:**

> /media/joy/DATA
> /media/joy/DATA2
> /media/joy/DATA1

`.absolute(file_name)` is getting `/home/joy/file_name` which is not what I want as `/media/joy/DATA`

The way I came up ,
I tried to called the linux command `lsblk` in paython , and use regular expression with key word "/media/joy" to filter the desire path, somehow I'm stock

tried code:

```
import os

import subprocess
a = subprocess.check_output(['lsblk'])

str_a = str(a)

# I split by "\n" cause that in erery line of str_a
str_a_splited = str_a.split("\n")


USB_info = [s for s in str_a_splited if "/media/joy" in s]



print("=  =   =   =   ")
print(USB_info)
```

and here is the output from tried code:

```
=  =   =   =   
["b'NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS\\nloop0    7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5\\nloop1    7:1    0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/582\\nloop2    7:2    0    62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1587\\nloop3    7:3    0 114.9M  1 loop /snap/core/13741\\nloop4    7:4    0 729.4M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-professional/302\\nloop5    7:5    0   284K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/14\\nloop6    7:6    0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16778\\nloop7    7:7    0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115\\nloop8    7:8    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535\\nloop9    7:9    0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2566\\nloop10   7:10   0 140.8M  1 loop /snap/skype/226\\nloop11   7:11   0  63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1623\\nloop12   7:12   0   115M  1 loop /snap/core/13886\\nloop13   7:13   0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/599\\nloop14   7:14   0 238.1M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1918\\nloop15   7:15   0 237.3M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1883\\nloop16   7:16   0  37.1M  1 loop /snap/hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004/2\\nloop17   7:17   0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17029\\nloop18   7:18   0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161\\nloop19   7:19   0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119\\nsda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk \\n\\xe2\\x94\\x9c\\xe2\\x94\\x80sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part \\n\\xe2\\x94\\x9c\\xe2\\x94\\x80sda2   8:2    0   513M  0 part /boot/efi\\n\\xe2\\x94\\x94\\xe2\\x94\\x80sda3   8:3    0   931G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell\\n                                 /\\nsdb      8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk \\n\\xe2\\x94\\x94\\xe2\\x94\\x80sdb1   8:17   1   3.8G  0 part /media/joy/DATA\\nsdc      8:32   1     0B  0 disk \\nsdd      8:48   1     0B  0 disk \\nsde      8:64   1     0B  0 disk \\nsdf      8:80   1     0B  0 disk \\nsdg      8:96   1  29.4G  0 disk \\n\\xe2\\x94\\x94\\xe2\\x94\\x80sdg1   8:97   1  29.4G  0 part /media/joy/DATA2\\nsdh      8:112  1   1.9G  0 disk \\n\\xe2\\x94\\x94\\xe2\\x94\\x80sdh1   8:113  1   1.9G  0 part /media/joy/DATA1\\nsr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  \\nsr1     11:1    1  1024M  0 rom  \\n'"]
```

the linux command `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1    7:1    0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/582
loop2    7:2    0    62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1587
loop3    7:3    0 114.9M  1 loop /snap/core/13741
loop4    7:4    0 729.4M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-professional/302
loop5    7:5    0   284K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/14
loop6    7:6    0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16778
loop7    7:7    0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
loop8    7:8    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop9    7:9    0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2566
loop10   7:10   0 140.8M  1 loop /snap/skype/226
loop11   7:11   0  63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1623
loop12   7:12   0   115M  1 loop /snap/core/13886
loop13   7:13   0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/599
loop14   7:14   0 238.1M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1918
loop15   7:15   0 237.3M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1883
loop16   7:16   0  37.1M  1 loop /snap/hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004/2
loop17   7:17   0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17029
loop18   7:18   0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop19   7:19   0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   513M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda3   8:3    0   931G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                 /
sdb      8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   3.8G  0 part /media/joy/DATA
sdc      8:32   1     0B  0 disk 
sdd      8:48   1     0B  0 disk 
sde      8:64   1     0B  0 disk 
sdf      8:80   1     0B  0 disk 
sdg      8:96   1  29.4G  0 disk 
└─sdg1   8:97   1  29.4G  0 part /media/joy/DATA2
sdh      8:112  1   1.9G  0 disk 
└─sdh1   8:113  1   1.9G  0 part /media/joy/DATA1
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sr1     11:1    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code a little and it works now as you expected:

```py
import os

import subprocess
a = subprocess.check_output(['lsblk'])


# I split by "\n" cause that in erery line of str_a
str_a_splited = a.split("\n")


USB_info = [s for s in str_a_splited if "/media/" in s]
found_path = []

for x in USB_info:
    for s in x.split(" "):
        if "/media/" in s:
            found_path.append(s)


print("=  =   =   =   ")
print(found_path)
```

and you don't need to convert the output of `subprocess` to `str` since it is in `str` format by default.I tested this on my PC and worked fine.

Comment: hi @iliya, I used the same code you provide, and here was what I got in result, can U take a look `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joy/fe_dir/damm.py", line 8, in <module>
    str_a_splited = a.split("\n")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
`

Comment: @fdu_account can you tell me the version of python you are using ?

Comment: @fdu_account find the problem. Code above works with python2 and for python3 you need to change line 8 with this: `str_a_splited = str(a).split("\n")`

Comment: `(base) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~$ python --version
Python 3.9.12` this is my python version, but thanks for ur helping that I solved the question.

Answer (score -1):

I add `.decode()` in case *TypeError* pop out

```
import os

import subprocess
a = subprocess.check_output(['lsblk'])


# I split by "\n" cause that in erery line of str_a
str_a_splited = a.decode().split("\n")


USB_info = [s for s in str_a_splited if "/media/" in s]
found_path = []

for x in USB_info:
    for s in x.split(" "):
        if "/media/" in s:
            found_path.append(s)


print("=  =   =   =   ")
print(found_path)
```